# localizing application non default strings?

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to localize my android application and I read up on how by reading this tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html but after looking through it, I couldn't figure out how to change the language.  I have the default values in res/values/strings.xml and I have my other strings in res/values-latin/strings.xml. but I cant figure out how to make my application use the strings in res/values-latin/strings.xml instead of the default.  Could someone explain this to me?

How about if someone clicks a change language button how could I inform the application to change all the strings?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Android will do it for you automatically.

> When a user runs your application:
>
> The Android system selects which resources to load, based on the
>   device's locale.

Example:

Suppose that your application's default language is English. Suppose also that you want to localize all the text in your application to French. In this case, you could create two alternative strings.xml files, each stored in a locale-specific resource directory:

```
res/values/strings.xml
```

Contains English text for all the strings that the application uses.

```
res/values-fr/strings.xml
```

Contain French text for all the strings.

If your Java code refers to **R.string.title**, here is what will happen at runtime:

If the device is set to any language other than French, Android will load **English title** from the **res/values/strings.xml** file.

If the device is set to French, Android will load **French title** from the **res/values-fr/strings.xml** file.

---

With latin it will not work. You should search alternative method.
My solution in java:

```
public final class English {
    String moon = "Moon";
    String earth = "Earth";
    String mars = "Mars";
}

public final class Latin {
    String moon = "Luna";
    String earth = "Terrae";
    String mars = "Mars in Latin";
}
```

Then in  your code you can aceess them:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text);
textView.setText( Latin.moon );
```

Comment: thanks for the response! how about for the case of my latin strings will it still know to load that. because I know that values-fr is already set in the android program